# Troubles with Rails 3 and classes in nested directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails project that I inherited.  I'm working on upgrading it from rails 2 to rails 3.  I'm at 3.0.15 right now, working my way up to 3.2.  In the app directory there is a support folder with classes in it.  Like so:

```
app/
  support/ 
    sweeper.rb
    grouped_list/ 
      item.rb
      list.rb
```

item.rb looks like this:

```
class Support::GroupedList::Item

  attr_accessor :name, :count, :link

  def initialize(name, count, link)
    @name = name
    @count = count
    @link = link
  end
end
```

In one of the controllers the Items class is called like this:

```
Support::GroupedList::Item.new name, count, link
```

when I try and load a page I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Support
```

My first thought was that the paths where not in the autoload so I added

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/support #{config.root}/app/support/grouped_list)
```

in my application.rb but that didn't change anything. After looking around for examples I found that people where creating empty module in their directory structure so I created a support.rb file in the support folder that looks like this:

```
module Support
end
```

Now my error changes to

```
uninitialized constant Support::GroupedList
```

Hey! That's interesting, I don't understand why it changed but its progress right?  So I add a grouped_list.rb file in the grouped_list directory.  It looks like this:

```
module Support::GroupedList
end
```

But then I get

```
Expected ***/app/support/grouped_list/grouped_list.rb to define GroupedList
```

Ugh! so I change it to:

```
module GroupedList
end
```

But then I'm back to:

```
uninitialized constant Support::GroupedList
```

So clearly there is some fundamental knowledge I'm missing about loading classes in modules.  This structure worked in rails 2 but breaks in rails 3.0.15.  I'd really like to understand so if anyone can help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GroupedList::Item

  attr_accessor :name, :count, :link

  def initialize(name, count, link)
    @name = name
    @count = count
    @link = link
  end
end
```

This should work. Then in your controller:

```
GroupedList::Item.new name, count, link
```

Also remember to restart your rails server/console, after you make these changes.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me.  But I still don't understand why it worked.  Would you mind explaining so I can be smarter.  =)

Comment: In Rails 3.x (not sure about the former versions), everything under app folder is autoloaded. Notice how you namespace models... in "models" directory. You don't wrap them with "Models::", right? The same story here, you omit "Support::" part.